# JSONStore initialization fails

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to get JSONStore working in MobileFirst 7 application on Lenovo A7000-a. But JSONStore throws error on initialization. However on my LG P880 it works fine. Here is the code of init:

```
var collections = {
    configuration : {
      searchFields : { id : 'string' }
    },
    taskList : {
      searchFields : { id : 'string' }
    },
    statistics : {
      searchFields : { subCategoryId : 'string' }
    },
    issues : {
      searchFields : {
        id            : 'string',
        internalId    : 'string',
        taskListId    : 'string',
        subCategoryId : 'string',
        subTaskId     : 'string'
      }
    },
    subCategories : {
      searchFields : {}
    },
    categories : {
      searchFields : {}
    },
    resultQueue : {
      searchFields : {
        taskListId: 'string'
      }
    }
  };

  WL.JSONStore.init(collections)
    .then( function (result) {
      angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['App']);
      });
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('ERROR: cannot initialize JSONStore');
    });
```

And here is the error I get:
[image]
Based on error I guess that this error fires because lenovo has 64-bit ARM processor (MT6752M). Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 installation to the latest available iFix from IBM Fix Central, which will contain the following fix:

PI43196 JSONSTORE DOES NOT CORRECTLY IDENTIFY X86_64 ARCHITECTURE  PROCESSORS ON MOBILE DEVICES

Comment: I've tried to download one of the fixes and got this [error message](http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=11_635719604068851772.png), I understand that some anonymous account can't access these resources, but what artifact exactly should I ask for from my company to download this? Some account with support subscription or what?

Comment: Only IBM customers and business partners can access this site. You need to download either the Studio plug-in or the CLI...

Comment: Just updated MF Studio to last version (7.0.0.00-20150706-1910). Then removed JSONStore feature and android environment from application-descriptor.xml, rebuilt project, added JSONStore and android environment back, rebuilt again and now it works. Thanks!